# How can I retain the value on "n" on my first call to this method and in further recursion calls?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public void staircase(int n)
{
    // I need to retain the value of "n" going forward in my recursion calls 
    // Also, everything needs to be done inside the method!

    int check = 0;

    if(n != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0;i< n; i++)
        {
            // method to draw
            if (check < (n - 1))
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
                check++;
            }
            else
                Console.Write("#");
        }

        if (check != 0)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            staircase(check);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "retain", but maybe you need to pass `n` as a second parameter called `prev_n` to `staircase` when you call it recursively.  It depends on why you need to retain it.

Comment: It would be possible to use an local function to capture `n` without explicitly passing it as a parameter. However, what's unclear to me is why you need to "retain" `n`. I could write this as an answer, but I don't know how to show you a working method.

Comment: The obvious answer is to replace `staircase(check)` with `staircase(n)`. That doesn't make a lot of sense though. I guess we need to understand how you plan to use two different values of `n` in your algorithm.

Comment: I was hoping to save the value of “n” in my first method call to some variable (for example) . So that I can use this constant value in all the recursive calls. For example : initially I pass n=6, so I want to store this value-6 and use this throughout all recursive calls (n value changes with all recursive calls). So I want to save the initial n value and use it other recursive loops. Also, I want to do this without changing the signature of the function or without declaring a variable outside the function.

Comment: So you want to store the *first* value of `n` that the initial caller provided.  I'd suggest using a public `Staircase` method with one parameter, and a private `StaircaseRecursive` method with two parameters, `n` and `original_n`. Every time you call `StaircaseRecursive`, you pass the same value for the `original_n` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a second parameter to the method and set it to some default value, possibly `null` (by making it a nullable `int`). Then you would set it to the value of `n` only if it's `null` (indicating that it's the first time the method is called), so it can be passed to subsequent recursive calls:

```
public void staircase(int number, int? original = null)
{
    // On the first iteration, 'original' should be null, so assign 'n' to it
    if (original == null) original = number;

    // * Other code remains the same *

    // Pass 'original' to recursive calls, which should be the first value of 'n'
    if (check != 0)
    {
        Console.Write("\n");
        staircase(check, original);
    }       

    // * Other code remains the same *
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a local method like this:

```
public void StairCase(int n)
{
    void StairCaseInner(int n_inner)
    {
        // you can still access `n` in here.
        
        Console.WriteLine(n);
        
        int check = 0;

        if (n_inner != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n_inner; i++)
            {
                // method to draw
                if (check < (n_inner - 1))
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    check++;
                }
                else
                    Console.Write("#");
            }

            if (check != 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                StairCaseInner(check);
            }
        }
    }

    StairCaseInner(n);
    
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I call `StairCase(5);` the output I get from this is:

```
5
    #
5
   #
5
  #
5
 #
5
#
```

I would love to know what the method is meant to do with the original `n`.